# JavaDocs for SpringBoot REST API or other known Architectures/Frameworks? Necessary?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, documentation, javadoc

After creating a SpringBootApp to supply REST Services, all according to official Spring Documentation but adding a Service Layer (who knows why Spring Docs ignores this), I've consider creating JavaDocs for the project.

Problem is... It's too redundant and all the effort would imply to explain explicit methods and classes like "Controller Method that provides GET service..." when the class is called Controller and method has @GetMapping tag. If official documentation is on the internet and you respected Arquitectural Design Patterns, why should you redo all the work that somebody has already done? I mean, if it was something purely original and imposible to understand, of course I would have to document everything till the most minuscule detail: but for this? Not sure...

What do you think? Am I being a lazy programmer or could you justify this lack of effort?

Comment: SO is not the place to ask others for opinions. This is a topic that should be regulated by your internal team or company or organization rules. Go and talk to your developer colleagues over it, if they find it useful (and would be ok to provide such documentation also).

Comment: I'm a student. It's for a project. I think this place is only for seniors. Sorry. Deleting my account.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to scare you away of SO! It's the complete opposite way: I have seen too many starting discussions (!) that were closed with a similar statement, but wanted to point you in this direction: the answer(s) would be opinionated and therefore might or might not be correct for your situation. It's totally depending on the circumstances. Juniors are highly welcome to SO - as long as they are willing to learn that one might have to reformulate a question until it fit's this places goals.

Comment: And to come back to your additions (please don't forget to add your current situation "it's for a students project" to your question!): Ask your future self: after one year, you have forgotten half of the project yet - would it be helpful to have the additional documentation, or would it be wasted time as everything is completely clear from the code alone?